# server python client c++ 10061

Tags: python, c++, server, client

I have:
1) TCP Server on python, TCP Client on Python - it works (Python 3.6.2 #import socket)
2) TCP Server on C++, TCP Client on C++ - it works (Ws2_32.dll)
3) Trying to connect C++ Client with Python Server - error 10061.
Server port is the same everywhere.
Cannot understand why.
Some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Reason was simple. No need to turn around port bytes:
port=socket.htons(port)
When i removed this operator, everything became ok.
It seems "bind" function do it itself.
But I had to spend 2 days to find it out